# Web scraping with bs4: when appending results to csv only the last two values are shown

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python e BS4.  I have read the other posts in Stack Overflow, but I cannot make it work!
The code I'm using is adapted from one used at school.
I'm trying to scrape the following website: https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve with BS4 and python 3.

I get all the information I need (username, server, link, comments..), however when appending the data to the csv file, I get different results:

1) For link,username, topic, question etc I get a different result for every line as expected

2) for comments and views I get only the last two values which keep repeating

```
def get_songs(url):

    index_page = BeautifulSoup(load_page(url), 'lxml') # Parse the page
    items = index_page.find(id='search-results') # Get the list on from the webpage
    if not items: # If the webpage does not contain the list, we should exit
        print('Something went wrong!', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit()
    data = list()

    for row in items.find_all(class_='title'):
        links = row.find_all('a', {"class": "title-link",}) 
        for link in links: 
            urls='https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com'+link.get('href')
        #print(urls)

        username = row.find(class_='username').text.strip()
        question = row.find(class_='title-span').text.strip()
        sentence = row.find('span')['title']
        serverzone = row.find(class_='realm').text.strip()
        #print(serverzone)
        topic = row.find('div', {'class':'discussion-footer byline opaque'}).find_all('a')[1].text.strip()
        #print(topic)
        date=row.find(class_='timeago').get('title')
        #print(date)

        #To access the comments and views, a request to the server must be made

        r = requests.get('https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve')
        #print(r)
        content=r.text
        #print(content)
        parser = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') # Parse the page
        #find the views
        viewclass = parser.find_all(class_='view-counts byline')
        for region in viewclass:
            views = region.find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
            print(views)
        #find the comments
        commentclass = parser.find_all(class_='num-comments byline')
        for region2 in commentclass:
            comments = region2.find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
            print(comments)

        # Store the data in a dictionary, and add that to our list
        data.append({
                    'number_of_comments':comments,
                    'link': urls,
                    'username': username,
                     'topic':topic,
                     'question':question,
                     'sentence':sentence,
                     'server':serverzone,
                     'date':date,
                     'number_of_views':views
                    })
    return data
```

When printing comments and views which result from the two loops, I see all of them, however when reading the csv file only the last two values of views and columns are shown..

For instance, the views are:506,641... till the last two values 842 and 544, the csv file just prints 842,544 repeatedly
I think there is a problem with the loops, I tried many alternatives but I couldn't make it work

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a second server request to access comments and view.
All you need is to change the pointer for your `row` variable:

```
for row in items.find_all(class_='discussion-list-item'):
```

So the access to the views and comments is now available

```
views = row.find(class_='view-counts byline').find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
comments = row.find(class_='num-comments byline').find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
```

Here is the code sample:

```
def load_page(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_songs(url):

    index_page = BeautifulSoup(load_page(url), 'lxml') # Parse the page
    items = index_page.find(id='search-results') # Get the list on from the webpage
    if not items: # If the webpage does not contain the list, we should exit
        print('Something went wrong!', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit()
    data = list()

    for row in items.find_all(class_='discussion-list-item'):
        links = row.find_all('a', {"class": "title-link",})
        for link in links:
            urls='https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com'+link.get('href')
        #print(urls)

        username = row.find(class_='username').text.strip()
        question = row.find(class_='title-span').text.strip()
        sentence = row.find('span')['title']
        serverzone = row.find(class_='realm').text.strip()
        #print(serverzone)
        topic = row.find('div', {'class':'discussion-footer byline opaque'}).find_all('a')[1].text.strip()
        #print(topic)
        date=row.find(class_='timeago').get('title')
        #print(date)
        views = row.find(class_='view-counts byline').find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
        comments = row.find(class_='num-comments byline').find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
        # Store the data in a dictionary, and add that to our list
        data.append({
                    'number_of_comments':comments,
                    'link': urls,
                    'username': username,
                     'topic':topic,
                     'question':question,
                     'sentence':sentence,
                     'server':serverzone,
                     'date':date,
                     'number_of_views':views
                    })
    return data

data = get_songs('https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve')
print(data)
```

Comment: That's such a stupid mistake, I thought I had to make another request to the server since initially  I was getting 'none'  and by looking on stackoverflow, this seemed to be potentially the solution! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Francesca you are welcome, could you please accept the answer and up it? :-)